# How do I know if $|G|=p^k > 1 $, then exists a normal subgroup of $G$ of order p?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have no idea how to prove that  if $|G|=p^k > 1 $, then exists a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p$, where $p$ is a prime.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use induction on $k$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the class equation, $p$-groups have nontrivial center; Cauchy's theorem gives us an element of prime order, and therefore there's a subgroup as required.